# How to store reference data using mongoose refs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm making a note app, each note will have multiple categories.

```
var NotesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    note: String, 
    favorite: {type: Boolean, default: false},
    category: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "categories" }]
},{ timestamps: { createdAt: 'created_at' } });

var Notes = mongoose.model('Notes', NotesSchema);

var CategoriesSchema = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    favorite: {type: Boolean, default: false}, 
})
var Categories = mongoose.model('Categories', CategoriesSchema);
```

I can do this with only one category but I don't know how it's done for multiple categories.

First I thought I need to store the categories, get each id and then store the note. Here's what I tried:

```
.get('/', (req, res) => {
    var data = {
        title : "scientific revolution",      
        note : " some note", 
        favorite : true,    
        category : [ 'science', 'books']
    }
    var catIds = [], seriesIds = [];

    data.category.map(cat =>{
        const category = new Categories({
            name: cat
        })
        category.save((err,data)=>{
            if(err) throw err; 
            catIds.push(data._id)
        })
    })
    data.category = catIds; 
    const note = new Notes(data)
    note.save((err, data)=>{
        if(err) throw err;
        res.json(data)
    })
})
```

The `catIds` array never gets the ids!

I'm totally new at using references. Didn't even know they existed.

Answer (score 1):

Your `ref` field should point to the **model name** not the table name.

In this case `Categories`.

I see you have write `{ref: 'categories'}` with small `c` but mongoose collection name is case sensitive and you should do `{ref: 'Categories'}`.

You can read more about mongoose case sensitivity in this [post](https://samwize.com/2014/03/07/what-mongoose-never-explain-to-you-on-case-sentivity/)

Comment: That was a type but still wanted to know something else.